# my work of solving a probability question

Tags: probability

Bob,Mali and Sarah each  toss a fair coin into the air.The probability of the coins landing with 2 heads and 1 tail in any order is?

my work:

1 tail
2 heads
theirs is 1/2 chance of the coins landing with 2 heads and 1 tail because its a 50/50 chance?

is this the correct way to solve the question and if not what would be the appropriate answer to this question?

Comment: Please choose the actual question as the title of your post.

Answer (score 2):

What about the other possibilities, such as $3$ heads?

The probability of getting HHT (by this order) is $\left(\frac12\right)^3=\frac18$. The probability pf getting HTH and of getting THH is also $\frac18$. So, and since each of these $3$ cases excludes the other $2$, the probability of getting some these possibilities is $\frac38\left(=3\times\frac18\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely not the way to work it out.

Consider this: there are eight possible sequences of coins.

$$\{HHH,HHT,HTH,THH,HTT,THT,TTH,TTT\}$$

How many of these correspond to two heads and one tails? Three. Thus, the probability is

$$\frac{\text{# of valid sequences}}{\text{# of total possible sequences}} = \frac 38$$

Answer (score 0):

That is not correct.

There are $8$ possible outcomes, $2$ for each coin.
Notice the coins are distinct (Bob's, Mali's and Sarah's).

Out of those $8$ outcomes, only $3$ fall in the prescribed pattern:

- Bob's lands tail, and the others land heads
- Mali's lands tail, and the others land heads
- Sarah's lands tail, and the others land heads

Hence, the probability is $3/8$.

Answer (score 0):

What no one else has mentioned...

Is this a problem from the **middle** of a probability book that the OP is self-studying?  If so, the OP has made a **work flow mistake**.  The OP should **first develop his intuition** by starting on page 1 of the book.

When attacking probability problems, it is critical to first develop one's **intuition**.

If the OP is taking this as part of a class, then the OP should go right to his teacher and explain that he has fallen behind in developing his intuition.

If, instead, the OP happened to encounter this as an isolated math puzzle that intrigued him, then he should find a knowledgeable math teacher, explain the situation, and have the teacher recommend a probability book for the OP to attack. Then the OP should attack the book before going anywhere near this puzzle.